# Erro com a função $_GET

Tags: php, mysql, get, switch

Pessoal minha dúvida é a seguinte, tenho a página `criareditarevento.php` que atualiza informações de um sistema de cadastro, porém preciso fazer com que a mensagem do update abra dentro da página `main.php` que é a página onde tem o `switch ($_GET['pag'])` padrão.

**PÁGINA CRIAREDITAREVENTO.PHP**

```
    <?
session_start();
 include("config.php");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sqlcontent = mysql_query("select * from usr_config");
$content = mysql_fetch_array($sqlcontent);
if(!isset($_SESSION[usr_name]) || empty($_SESSION[usr_name]) || !isset($_SESSION[usr_level]) || empty($_SESSION[usr_level]))
{
session_destroy();
session_unset();
die('
<div align="center">
 <font face="verdana" size="2" color="#000">Você precisa estar logado para visualizar essa página...</font>
</div>
');
}
include("func.php");

$update = clean($_GET[update]);
$getprof = mysql_query("select * from usr_users where username = '$_SESSION[usr_name]'");
$teste = mysql_query("select * from usr_users where username = '$_SESSION[usr_name]'");
$prof = mysql_fetch_array($getprof);
?>


<? if(!$update) { ?>
</font>
<form action="criareditarevento.php?update=update" method="post">
<font color="#FFFFFF">
<b><u><font size="1">Sua Conta</font></u></b><font size="1"><br />
<font color="#000000"><br />
Nome: <? echo("<b>$_SESSION[usr_name]</b>");?><br />
<br />
Email:<br />
</font></font></font><font color="#000000" size="1" face="Verdana">
<input class="subbutton" name="email" type="text" value="<? echo("$prof[email]");?>" size="40"?>
</font><font size="1" color="#000000"><br />
Site/Blog:<br />
</font><font color="#000000" size="1" face="Verdana">
<input class="subbutton" name="avator" type="text" value="<? echo("$prof[avator]");?>" size="50"?>
</font><font size="1" color="#000000"><br>
Hobbie:<br />
</font><font color="#000000" size="1" face="Verdana">
<input class="subbutton" name="hobbie" type="text" value="<? echo("$prof[hobbie]");?>" size="50"?>
</font><font size="1" color="#000000"><br />
<br />
<u><b>Trocar senha</b></u><br />
<em>Se não quiser trocar a Senha, Não 
preencha os Campos Abaixo</em><br />
<br />
Atual Senha:<br />
</font><font color="#000000" size="1" face="Verdana">
<input class="subbutton" name="oldpw" type="password" size="30" />
</font><font size="1" color="#000000">
<br />
Nova Senha:<br />
</font><font color="#000000" size="1" face="Verdana">
<input class="subbutton" name="new1" type="password" size="30" />
</font><font size="1" color="#000000">
<br />
Repetir Nova Senha:<br />
</font><font color="#000000" size="1" face="Verdana">
<input class="subbutton" name="new2" type="password" size="30" />
</font><font size="1" color="#000000">
<br />
<br />
</font><font color="#000000" size="1" face="Verdana">
<input class="subbutton" type="submit" value="Atualizar" />
</font>

</form>
<font size="1" color="#000000">
<? }

elseif($update==update)
{
$email = clean($_POST[email]);
$avator = clean($_POST[avator]);
$hobbie = clean($_POST[hobbie]);
$updateemail = mysql_query("update usr_users set email = '$email', avator = '$avator', hobbie = '$hobbie' where username = '$_SESSION[usr_name]'");
$oldpw = clean($_POST[oldpw]);
$new1 = clean($_POST[new1]);
$new2 = clean($_POST[new2]);
if($oldpw!="")
{
$checkpass = md5($oldpw);
$check2 = mysql_query("select * from usr_users where password = '$checkpass' and username = '$_SESSION[usr_name]'");
$check = mysql_num_rows($check2);
if($check==1)
{
if($new1==$new2)
{
$password = md5($new1);
$updatepass = mysql_query("update usr_users set password = '$password' where username = '$_SESSION[usr_name]'");
echo("Your password has been updated!<br />");
}
else echo("The two passwords do not match!");
}
else echo("The password you entered does not match your current password.");
}
echo("Your Preferences have been updated!");
} ?>
</font><font size="1" color="#FFFFFF">  </font>
</div></td>
```

**PÁGINA MAIN.PHP:**

```
<?php
     switch ($_GET['pag'])
      {
        case "criareditarevento": include("criareditarevento.php"); break;
        case "teste2": include("teste2.php"); break;
        case "desconectar": include("desconectar.php"); break;
                   default: include("principal.php"); break;

      }
?>
```

Aguardo ajuda :D

Comment: Não está claro o que você quer fazer. a página main.php será chamada após a atualização?

Comment: Tente mudar `<form action="criareditarevento.php?update=update" method="post">` para `<form action="main.php?page=criareditarevento&update=update" method="post">`

Comment: > Obrigado <b>Alisson Acioli</b>, deu certo :D

Answer (score 1):

No action do form, você está usando a variável get "update". Já no seu switch, você verifica a variável "pag" e o valor dela está update.

Altere o action do form para:

criareditarevento.php?pag=criareditarevento

Answer (score 1):

Creio que o erro seja somente este:

```
elseif($update==update)
```

Altere para:

```
elseif($update == "update")
```

Outra coisa **extremamente importante:**

- Não use **short tags** = `<? echo 'bla' ?>`. Procure na internet, há vários motivos.
- Não execute instruções diretamente no banco através da sua view. NUNCA!
- Idente seu código
- Veja bem a segurança do seu código, não está la essas coisas
- Procure utilizar um framework leve e mais simples em seus projetos, ao menos para entender como tudo funciona e então se desejar "crie o seu" (eu não recomendo... é bem mais viável utilizar um framework e adaptar ele ao seu trabalho, do que reinventar a roda).

Digo isso apenas para agregar maior valor ao seu código (e a você).

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar qual resposta dos usuários resolveu o seu problema.